# how to upload and read a file with express

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have question.I've looked at some questions here, but I can't get the answer.My question is, I want to upload and read a json file, I try with "multer" but couldn't.So I want to put the file I upload to the result variable. Can you help me? How can I achieve this?

HTML;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form action="/import" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="filename">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload  = multer({
  dest: 'uploads/' // "uploads"
}); 

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

route.post("/import", upload.single("filename") (req, res, next) => {
  var result = require(# I want to send the json file I uploaded here, and I need to see the contents of the json file as is #)
  res.json(result)

      res.redirect("/")
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Can you show us how you tried using `multer`?

Comment: here and in other samples, but I could not do so I erased my code. I'm looking for a useful answer

Comment: Without code, we can not help. You might wanna read the docs and try something out: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

Comment: how is it possible to see the contents of the json file with multer any example???

Comment: @AnandUndavia I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `upload.single()` parses the data stream and saves as a file based on the configuration. In your case, it will look for `filename` field in the incoming request and save the file in the `uploads/` folder. The metadata of the file is available in `req.file` object. You can simply do `console.log(req.file)` to see the information.

To read the content of the file, you can use `req.file.path` field. Here is how:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

/** In the controller */
const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, req.file.path);
const jsonString = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf-8");
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(jsonObject);
```

Here is how the complete `server.js` would look like:

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const upload = multer({
    dest: "uploads/" // "uploads"
});

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

const route = express.Router();
route.post("/import", upload.single("filename"), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, req.file.path);
    const jsonString = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf-8");
    const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    console.log(jsonObject);
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.use(route);

app.listen(3000);
```

I have added some parts which were missing from your snippet ( like `express.Router` ). They might be different though.

Comment: First of all I thank you but I get an error : Error: Unexpected field

Comment: Umm my snippet works fine on my machine, Make sure you have a comma after `upload.single()` which is there in my snippet but missing from yours :)